# MySQL "ON DELETE CASCADE" is too powerful

Tags: sql, mysql, database, data-structures, constraints

hey, following problem here: i have table with persons that have one location, if i delete the location for the location table, i don't wont to lose the assigned persons. ive a entry in the location with the id=1 and the name is: "No location". and that what I'm trying to do, but i fail!

```
ALTER TABLE `persons`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `persons_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`location_id`)
  REFERENCES `locations` (`id`) ON DELETE SET `location_id` = 1;
```

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ON DELETE SET DEFAULT` (and make 1 the default value), or `ON DELETE SET NULL`.
A third option is to manually set all ids to 1 before deleting.

Comment: thanks, it looks like innoDB doesn't support SET DEFAULT so i have to use SET NULL :(

Comment: Strange. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html says it should support it.